# Turn post into simple slideshow

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, loop, customization

I'm new to WordPress development, but I've coded a template page for a friend. I'm trying to convert the following html into a single post:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner_box">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="images/photo1.jpg">
          <div class="title">
            This is the title &#9654;
          </div>
        </li>
        <li><img src="images/photo2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/image3.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/image4.jpg"></li>
        <li class="text_box">
          <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
          nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
          eu, pretium quis, sem</p>
          <p>Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel,
          aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut,
          imperdiet a, venenatis</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

However, I am not sure where to begin. The loop in the `index.php` seems far too simple for this kind of customisation. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking. What have you tried? How are you "converting"? It is not at all clear what you are doing.

Comment: Is each list item `<li>` a "slide"?

Comment: Yes, everything within a `li` is a slide. Some have multiple paragraphs, some have a single image.